# Not getting the data from session cache, instead hitting the DB

Tags: c#, nhibernate, orm

I have a Mapping for Category:

```
<class name="Category" table="Category" lazy="true">
        <cache usage="read-write"/>   // enabled Entity Cache

        <id name="CategoryId" column="pk_cat_id">
          <generator class="hilo"/>
        </id>

        <property name="Name" column="name" type="string" length="50" />
        <many-to-one name="ParentCategory" class="Category" 
                     column="parent_cat_id" cascade="save-update"/>

        <bag name="childCategories" cascade="all" inverse="true">
          <key column="parent_cat_id"/>
          <one-to-many class="Category"/>      
        </bag>

</class>
```

I wrote:

```
    using (ISession sess = factory.OpenSession())
    using (ITransaction tran = sess.BeginTransaction())
    {
        IList<Category> products = sess.CreateCriteria(typeof(Category))
                                       .SetCacheable(true)
                                       .List<Category>();   // hits DB -- no issues

        IList<Category> prod = sess.CreateCriteria(typeof(Category))
                                 .SetCacheable(true)
                                 .Add(Restrictions.Eq("CategoryId", 4128768))
                                 .List<Category>();        // hits DB  -- WHY?

        tran.Commit();
    }
```

From above as you can see, for the first query it gets all the rows in the table. Second time when i tried to access one of the rows already present as a result of first query(CategoryId"= 4128768). Then according to nHibernate it should be there in session cache and it should not hit the DB again.

Where am I Wrong? Am I ...

Kindly help me!!

Answer (score 0):

What you are experiencing is correct, because in fact, you are issuing **two different** queries. At the time of execution of the second query - it is not clear, if/that the second will return the sub-set result of the first. NHibernate does not provide any comparison like: query without WHERE contains all results as the query with some WHERE clause. There still could be different page for example...

By default, NHibernate does cache queries (with the same params) and the resulted set of returned IDs. For each ID there is also the entity cache. So, if you load stuff lazily, already loaded entity *(cached in the first level by its ID)* is used.

But in this case - both queries are not the same. They do have different parameteres *(and also - in common - there already could happen some write operation inside of the same transaction)*

1. no WHERE clause
2. WHERE build from `.Add(Restrictions.Eq("CategoryId", 4128768))`

Comment: but I have added: <cache usage="read-write"/> in my mapping. Isn't it entity caching?

Comment: The 1) entity caching is when we call `session.Get<TEntity>(id)`. When we call `session.CreateCriteria()` it is a query cache. Truth is, that items loaded by each query are cached in the entity cache (by id). But because you have called 2 **different** queries... both of them had to be executed. Does it make more sense now?

Comment: One more thing, both the queries in my example are with in same session. So, Query caching  and Entity caching makes no sense here as that works across sessions. I guess here Session cache comes into play. Besides, kindly tell me where did you read session.Get(id) is entity caching? Did you go through second last paragraph of this: http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2009/02/09/quickly-setting-up-and-using-nhibernate-s-second-level-cache.aspx

Comment: I see, I was wrong in reading "session cache" ... and thinking about the query cache. You are right. But the principle is the same. I will adjust my answer...